# Azure Webjob is slowing down with parallel executions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I have a working long running (scheduled) calculation running in an Azure webjob that typically takes 500-600 seconds to execute.

However when I start multiple calculations I noticed performance degradation.
With 2 calculations running at once, the average running time is 1000-1100 seconds. With 3 , 1600-1800seconds, etc...

So there is no 'time gain' by running multiple calculations at once. 
And there are plenty of 'resources' left :  the database usage is less than 10%. The CPU of the Service App  <10%, Memory usage less than 40%.

Is Azure throttling the (parallel) execution of webjobs functions?

Just for the fun of it I copied the webjob logic into a console app. And started 5 different instances of this console app on my laptop (using the same db settings etc). Average running time again 500-600 seconds. So my code or database is not the bottleneck.  (DB usage increased to 20% during this test).

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of Service Plan do you have in terms of CPU cores etc. also are you doing something that might be locking a resource, I had a similar issue in the past converting a PDF and finally found the 3rd party library was locking the file on each request so it didn't matter how many parallel threads I ran or CPU cores I had

Comment: The app service running the webjob is on plan S1

Comment: Well S1 is a single core so I'm guessing on your laptop you have more than 1 core? Are you using asynchronous DB calls to avoid your single core on the S1 getting stuck waiting for a response perhaps rather than spending the waiting time doing more calculations in another thread?